# Почему этот кусок кода приводит к 500 ошибке на сайте?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-500

Почему этот кусок кода приводит к 500 ошибке на [сайте](http://35.170.225.58/?portfolio=alina)?

```
add_shortcode('in', 'in');
function in(){
    global $post;
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'work')){
        $work = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'work');
        foreach ($work as $options) {
            foreach ($options as $key) {
                if ($key == "in") {
                    $hour = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'app_price_1hour');
                    $2hour = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'app_price_2hour');
                    $night = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'app_price_night');
                    $output = "<h4>Апартаменты</h4><p><b>Цена за час:</b> &#8362;".$hour[0]."</p><p><b>Цена за 2 часа:</b> &#8362;".$2hour[0]."</p><p><b>Цена за ночь:</b> &#8362;".$night[0]."</p>";
                    return $output;
                }
            }
        }
        unset($work, $options, $key, $output, $hour, $2hour, $night);
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in functions.php on line 422

Comment: Зачем unset, можно полюбопытствовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя имена переменных начинать с цифр.

[Читаем мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics.php): Правильное имя переменной должно начинаться с буквы или символа подчеркивания и состоять из букв, цифр и символов подчеркивания в любом количестве.

Вообще, код довольно грязный. Нет проверки на то, что $post существует. Совершенно ненужный unset - вся память локальных переменных и так освобождается при выходе из функции. Нет проверки на то, что $hour[0] и проч. существуют (get_post_meta в вашем варианте может вернуть пустой array() ). Нет возврата пустой строки в самом конце - это означает, что функция вернёт null, что может вызвать неприятные последствия.

Оформленный по стандартам кодирования WordPress код выглядит так:

```
add_shortcode( 'in', 'in' );
function in() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post ) {
        $work = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'work' );
        if ( $work ) {
            foreach ( $work as $options ) {
                foreach ( $options as $key ) {
                    if ( 'in' === $key ) {
                        $hour   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'app_price_1hour', true );
                        $hour2  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'app_price_2hour', true );
                        $night  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'app_price_night', true );
                        $output =
                            '<h4>Апартаменты</h4><p><b>Цена за час:</b> &#8362;' . $hour .
                            '</p><p><b>Цена за 2 часа:</b> &#8362;' . $hour2 . '</p><p><b>Цена за ночь:</b> &#8362;' .
                            $night . '</p>';

                        return $output;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```